# How to get the location of config file used by mailutils

Tags: software-installation

I installed `mailutils` with following command in my ubuntu system.

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

But I am unable to send message with this

```
pstree | mail -s "PSTREE RESULT" xxxx.gmail.com
```

When I was installing mailutils I set gmail.com as mail provider.

Now I want to find the mailutils config file. But I don't know where it is. How can I know which config file mailutils is using?

I tried to search in my system with this

```
find . -name 'mailutils.rc' | less
```

And this

```
ls -R | grep 'mainutils[.]rc'
```

But couldn't find the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer – the config file is:

```
/etc/mailutils.rc
```

As described in documentation the main site-wide configuration file is:

```
<SYSCONFDIR>/mailutils.rc
```

To get the `SYSCONFDIR` of `mailutils` execute the commands below:

```
> sudo apt-get install libmailutils-dev
> mailutils-config --info sysconfdir
SYSCONFDIR=/etc
```

If this file does not exist - create it.

Same for all mailutils binaries, e.g.

```
> mail.mailutils --show-config-options | grep SYSCONFDIR
SYSCONFDIR=/etc     - System configuration directory
```

---

More about the correct configuration [here](http://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html#SEC8).

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023 `mail --config-verbose` shows the configuration files used.